# Django ListView с установленным allow_empty=True генерирует 404-ю ошибку

Tags: django, pagination

Столкнулся со странным. Вот примитивный CBV:

```
class PublicationList(ListView):
    model = Publication
    template_name = 'publications.html'
    paginate_by = 20
    allow_empty = True
```

Предположим, что в базе 60 экземпляров модели Publication. Тогда PublicationList должен отображать 3 страницы с данными, а четвёртую пустую. Вот только он на 4-й странице мне выдаёт 404-ю ошибку (EmptyPage: That page contains no results), игнорируя параметр allow_empty. Почему? Я что-то упускаю?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы немного неправильно понимаете назначение этого атрибута

allow_empty сделан для обработки ситуации, когда у вас список пустой изначально. Если он выставлен в True, тогда вам выведется страница без результатов. Если False, то django сгенерирует стандартную ошибку 404. Больше никакой разницы. [Взгляните на код](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.9.7/django/views/generic/list.py#L158)

Страница, на которой нет результатов, должна возвращать 404 в любом случае, это правильно